# How to resize bitmap image with createdScaleBitmap and without blur

Tags: android, android-studio, bitmap, android-sqlite

I want to capture image from camera and store it in sqlite. I resize it before saving.
I use this code it is work but i get a blurring image when i get a fullscreen image wen i display it.

```
public Bitmap resizeBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    int reqWidth = 900;
    int reqHeight = 900;
    RequestSizeOptions options = null;
    try {
        if (reqWidth > 0 && reqHeight > 0 && (options == RequestSizeOptions.RESIZE_FIT ||options == RequestSizeOptions.RESIZE_INSIDE || options == RequestSizeOptions.RESIZE_EXACT || options ==RequestSizeOptions.RESIZE_CENTRE_CROP)) {

            Bitmap resized = null;
            if (options == RequestSizeOptions.RESIZE_EXACT) {
                resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, reqWidth, reqHeight, false);
            } else {
                int width = bitmap.getWidth();
                int height = bitmap.getHeight();
                float scale = Math.max(width / (float) reqWidth, height / (float) reqHeight);
                if (scale > 1 || options == RequestSizeOptions.RESIZE_FIT) {
                    resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (int) (width / scale), (int) (height / scale), false);
                }
                if (scale > 1 || options == RequestSizeOptions.RESIZE_CENTRE_CROP) {
                    int smaller_side = (height-width)>0?width:height;
                    int half_smaller_side = smaller_side/2;
                    Rect initialRect = new Rect(0,0,width,height);
                    Rect finalRect = new Rect(initialRect.centerX()-half_smaller_side,initialRect.centerY()-half_smaller_side,
                            initialRect.centerX()+half_smaller_side,initialRect.centerY()+half_smaller_side);
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,  finalRect.left, finalRect.top, finalRect.width(), finalRect.height(), null, true);
                    //keep in mind we have square as request for cropping, otherwise - it is useless
                    resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, reqWidth, reqHeight, false);
                }

            }
            if (resized != null) {
                if (resized != bitmap) {
                    bitmap.recycle();
                }
                return resized;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w("AIC", "Failed to resize cropped image, return bitmap before resize", e);
    }
    return bitmap;
```

This is the code, i use resize in this function. these function are in model class.

```
 this.image = bitmapToString(resizeBitmap(image));

 private static String bitmapToString(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

the camera intent

```
 Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
           startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1);
```

NB: I save a image in sqlite and i display it on fullsceen.

Comment: Can you please start your post with the code for the used camera intent? And also tell/show how you obtained that bitmap you use for resizeBitmap();

Comment: And please tell the values of                 int width = bitmap.getWidth();
                int height = bitmap.getHeight(); Finally also tell the width and height of the `resized` bitmap.